# Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_OLDER_SDK] using google material dialog

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

I am new to Android and trying to use google material design.
I am getting error `"Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_OLDER_SDK]"`,I can't understand what should I do.

Here is my Application's gradle:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.2.0'
    }
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

repositories {
    jcenter()
}

dependencies {
    compile "com.android.support:support-v4:21.0.2"
    compile "com.android.support:support-v13:21.0.2"
    compile "com.android.support:cardview-v7:21.0.2"
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.+'
}

// The sample build uses multiple directories to
// keep boilerplate and common code separate from
// the main sample code.
List<String> dirs = [
    'main',     // main sample code; look here for the interesting stuff.
    'common',   // components that are reused by multiple samples
    'template'] // boilerplate code that is generated by the sample template process

android {
    compileSdkVersion "android-MNC"
    buildToolsVersion "22.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion "MNC"
        targetSdkVersion "MNC"
    }

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
    }

    sourceSets {
        main {
            dirs.each { dir ->
                java.srcDirs "src/${dir}/java"
                res.srcDirs "src/${dir}/res"
            }
        }
        androidTest.setRoot('tests')
        androidTest.java.srcDirs = ['tests/src']

    }

}
```

what should I have to change in my gradle to remove this runtime error.

Please help me.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Change the following:

```
compileSdkVersion 22

defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 10
        targetSdkVersion 22
    }
```

With the aforementioned you'd be able to compile on Android phones and tablets running API level 10 (Gingerbread) and above. And it will target on Android M(API Level 22). Be sure that you have installed these 2 SDKs from the Android SDK Manager.

Answer (score -1):

This failure is caused by the fact that the device's SDK you are testing on is below the requirements you have set in the Android Manifest. Go in the Manifest and lower the SDK requirements or test on a device with a newer SDK. (Example: you have specified your app to be for devices with Android 5.1(SDK 22) or higher, but you are testing it on a device with Android 4.1.2 (SDK 16))